# innerHTML on DOM?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I have this function that switches the HTML contents from one element on a page to the another.  The issue I am having is the when first iteration of this function is ran it keeps the original HTML values.  I thought the below code would simply overwrite the current contents.  First am I wrong?

Second, I am using Ajax to call content.  Could this be the cause where some how the DOM doesn't see the change?

Here is my code:

```
function subNavContent ( ) {    
    //If ID is the reference.
    //navContent = document.getElementByID('pageNav').innerHTML;
    navContent = document.getElementsByClassName('pageNav')[0].innerHTML;   
    document.getElementById('subNav').innerHTML = navContent;
    return;}
```

The HTML elements I call to be switched:

```
            <nav id="subNav" class="aniSubNavOpen drop-shadow lifted">
            </nav>

            <div class="pageNav">
            <h1 data-title="Welcome to The Mind Company">
            <a>Welcome to The Mind Company</a></h1> 
            </div>
```

Ajax call (and other stuff for sake of completeness.)

```
function subNavContent ( ) {    
    navContent = document.getElementsByClassName('pageNav')[0].innerHTML;   

    document.getElementById('subNav').innerHTML = navContent;}

function subNavLoader ( ) {
    var subNav = document.getElementById( 'subNav' );
    var tmp = '';

    if (subNav.className === 'aniSubNavClose' ) {
            tmp = 'aniSubNavOpen';  }
        else {
            tmp = 'aniSubNavClose';}

        subNav.className = tmp;
        return;}

function sectionAssure( classID, type ) {
    subNavLoader ( );

    setTimeout( function ( ) {

        var tmp = '';
        var sel = document.getElementsByTagName('section');

        for (var i=0; i<sel.length; i++){

            if (sel[i].id == classID) { tmp = 'block' } else { tmp = 'none' }
            sel[i].style.display = tmp;  }  

        subNavLoader ( ); }, ( 1500 ) );  }

function loadContent ( classID, url, type ) {   
    var xmlhttp;

    if ( window.XMLHttpRequest ) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200 ) {
                document.getElementById( classID ).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;}};   

        xmlhttp.open( "GET", url, true );           
        xmlhttp.send( );            
        subNavContent ( );}  
    return;  }
```

Comment: In your example you don't have element with class pageNav and you have two elements with ID subNav.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your objects with `class="pageNav"` and `id="subNav"` exist and `pageNav` has the desired content in it the first time you run the `subNavContent()` function, then the contents of the first object with `class="pageNav"` will be copied to the object with `id="subNav"`.  Note - this is not moving contents, but making a copy of the HTML and assigning it to the object `subNav`.  It will replace the previous contents of `subNav`.

If it is not working the first time you call it, then it's probably because one of the two objects doesn't exist yet or the contents of `pageNav` is not yet there when you run the function.

In addition, you cannot have two elements with the same id.  Your HTML shows two elements with `id="subNav"`.  There should only ever be one element with a given ID.  That's why `document.getElementByid()` only returns one element.

Also, the HTML in your question doesn't show any object with a `class="pageNav"`.

It is also possible that there is an issue with how you are making the ajax call and calling this function after the ajax call has completed.  You will have to show us your ajax code for us to comment on that.  If, for example, you weren't waiting until the success handler of the ajax call gets called, then the new content wouldn't be in the page yet the first time you ran the function.

---

**EDIT:** after looking at the actual code for the ajax call in the OP's actual page.

I can confirm that the way you are calling `subNavContent()` in your ajax call is incorrect.  This code will not work because you call `subNavContent()` before the new content has been loaded into the page.  This is your existing version of the code:

```
function loadContent ( classID, url, type ) {   
    var xmlhttp;
    var dir = getDir ( type );

    if ( window.XMLHttpRequest ) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200 ) {
                document.getElementById( classID ).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;}};   

        xmlhttp.open( "GET", dir + url, true );             
        xmlhttp.send( );

        subNavContent ( );}  
    return;  }
```

You are calling `subNavContent()` right after sending your ajax request.  You can only run this call AFTER the response has been received and the data has been put in your page.  You could change it to this:

```
function loadContent ( classID, url, type ) {   
    var xmlhttp;
    var dir = getDir ( type );

    if ( window.XMLHttpRequest ) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200 ) {
                document.getElementById( classID ).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                subNavContent ( );
            }
        }   

        xmlhttp.open( "GET", dir + url, true );             
        xmlhttp.send( );

    }  
    return;  
}
```

Also, you have an extremely difficult bracing style to read, comprehend, prevent making mistakes and to edit.

Comment: To you **Note** this is what I am trying to accomplish.  I do understand what you mean about id vs class, and corrected my original post code(thank you, didn't notice I double pasted).  As for the timming of the function load I believe I have it in the correct place; just after I call 'http.send()'.  What my script does is load the div with 'class="pageNav"' from the .html file being called into the template by ajax where the 'id="subNav"' is located (Hope that makes sense).  It is basically each pages sub navigation links.

Comment: Thought it would be better then calling outside the page to decrease lag time.   Here is a link to my site I am working on; please not I may be doing some playing if things look way off:  [The Mind Company](http://www.themindspot.com)

Comment: @BrandonClark - just after calling `.send()` is probably NOT the right place, but you haven't included that code so we can't say for sure.  With ajax calls, if you want code to run after the call has been processed, you HAVE to wait for the response and only run your code when the response has been received.  We'd have to see your ajax code and when you're calling this function to advise more specifically.

Comment: @BrandonClark - I don't know what "calling outside the page" means so I can't comment on that.

Comment: @BrandonClark - I've looked at your actual page and confirmed that the problem is when you are calling `subNavContent()`.  You need to call it in `onreadystatechange` when the correct `readyDtate` value is seen when you have the response and the response has been added to your page already.  I've added a fixed version of the code to my answer.

Comment: I see what you mean about the onreadystate and made the proper adjustments, this made sure it loads properly for sure. This however did not resolve my issue. The same contents of my home page class="pageNav" gets copied each time the function is ran. I now see this is because I am not loading the proper array value for the section being called.

Comment: Any advice on how I can pass the array id of the current page as it is loaded into the DOM(If you dont understand I will go into further detail).  I am thinking maybe there is someway I can clear the DOM of the class="pageNav" before the new one is loaded(Will begin to look into this). Sorry you seem to understand the realm of my questions better than most.

Comment: @BrandonClark - I don't really understand what you're asking.

Comment: went into my detail at [Stack Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001681/idea-on-content-passing-help-needed)

Answer (score 1):

Your function is not switching the content, it is copying it. innerHTML is a string, not the actual elements contained in pageNav.

To move the content you would have to select all the children elements from pageNav and append them to subNav (using appendChild).

Comment: copying as a string works fine. If I used append this would mean much more need less iterations that could be accomplished by one simple one.