# Idea on content passing. Help needed

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, innerhtml, ecmascript-5

**Core Question**

I need help coming up with a concept to achieve my goal.  I am having a problem coming up with an idea to how I can navigate the DOM properly with the method I have chosen.

---

**The Goal**

You should know what I am doing first:

I use ajax to call HTML content into a `<section>` element of my template.  I then call from those HTML contents an `class="pageNav"` tagged element that holds the sub navigation for it and copies it to a `id="subNav"` located in the main template. I do this when the new content is being called from the onStateChange event with this:

```
function subNavContent (  ) {  
    var navContent = document.getElementsByClassName('pageNav')[0]; 
    document.getElementById('subNav').innerHTML = navContent.innerHTML;
}
```

---

Now the issue I have with doing this is I must assign the proper array value to achieve this:

```
// i is the current content pages sub navigation
navContent = document.getElementsByClassName('pageNav')[i]
```

To be more clear the `class="pageNav"` are loaded into the DOM only when the user calls the page content, this is what specifies `navContent[i]` position.  So this is my dilemma.

Example: Home page is loaded `contentNav[0]` location. Contact is loaded by user next this would be `contentNav[1]` location for the `class="pageNav"`.

---

**The real questions?**

Is there was some way I could pass the array value of the page as it's loading into the DOM like in my example or not?

Could I maybe delete the `class="pageNav"` contents from the DOM after it copies to reset the array value of `class="pageNav"` to `navContent[0]` when it is ran for the next page?

---

**Further efforts with my idea**
I have being toying with this idea but with no success.  What I was thinking was to delete `class="pageNav"` for that content from the DOM after it is transfered like so:

```
function subNavClear ( ) {
    var wrap = document.getElementById('contentBody');
    var nav = document.getElementsByClassName('pageNav')[0];
    wrap.removeChild(nav);
}
```

so the resulting functions would be initiate in this order:

```
subNavContent (  );
    subNavClear ( );
```

I thought this would allow me to not worry about the array value of `contentNav[0]`.  I would think because I delete it from the DOM after it is created and copied that the next one to load would be assigned `contentNav[0]`.

Take a look if you like: [The Mind Company](http://www.themindspot.com).

---

**Snipplets per request**
This code does as explained.

html:

```
<body>
<!-- Header Areas: (Constent visual)--> 
<header>
    <div id="headTopRow">
        <div id="headerElement">  

            <nav id="subNav" class="aniSubNavOpen drop-shadow lifted">
            </nav>

        </div>
    </div>

</header>

<!-- Content Areas: (Variable visual)-->
<div id="contentBody">
    <br>
    <section class="aniDown" id="homePage">
        <script>checkPage ( 'homePage', 'home.html', 'main');</script>
    </section>
    <section class="aniDown" id="aboutPage"></section>
    <section class="aniDown" id="lessonsPage"></section>
    <section class="aniDown" id="productPage"></section>
    <section class="aniDown" id="contactPage"></section>
</div>

<!-- Footer Area: (Constant visual)-->
<footer>
</footer>
</body>
```

Transition functions:

```
function subNavContent (  ) {  
    var navContent = document.getElementsByClassName('pageNav')[0]; 
    document.getElementById('subNav').innerHTML = navContent.innerHTML;
}

    function sectionAssure( classID, url ) {        
            var tmp = '';
            var sel = document.getElementsByTagName('section');

            for (var i=0; i<sel.length; i++){
                if (sel[i].id == classID) { 
                    tmp = 'block'; 
                } 
                else {
                    tmp = 'none'; 
                }
                sel[i].style.display = tmp;  
            }  
    }

    function loadContent ( classID, url, type ) {   
        var xmlhttp;

        if ( window.XMLHttpRequest ) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200 ) {
                    document.getElementById( classID ).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                    subNavContent ( );
                }
            };

        xmlhttp.open( "GET", url, true );             
        xmlhttp.send( );  
        }  
        return;  
    }

    function checkPage ( classID, url ) {
        sectionAssure ( classID, url );     
        loadContent ( classID, url );  
    }
```

**Solution!!**

Thanks to @Dennis for giving me this idea.  Although I used a different method the principle is the same.

```
function subNavContent ( classID ) {  
    var sec = document.getElementById( classID );
    document.getElementById('subNav').innerHTML = sec.getElementsByClassName('pageNav')[0].innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell what you're asking, though I can see you put in some effort

Comment: @Juan Mendes I know. Sorry, maybe there is somewhere I can clarify for you and others?  It was already so long of a question and I didnt want to make it longer.

Comment: you should look at pjax: http://pjax.heroku.com/

Comment: @Billy Moon Thank you, but I have avoided jQuery so far and don't plan on loading that massive thing for one function.

Comment: @Juan Mendes I made some clarifications, hope it helps.

Comment: Do you have a sample page that we can look at?

Comment: I'll work at adding it to my base template(0 styling, bare content)  for now you can see my home site: [The Mind Company](http://www.themindspot.com). In exams sorry if I don,t respond right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manually setting `display:block` and `display:none`, you could use a class.  Select the section that is `.active`, and select the pageNav from there:

```
var navContent = document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0].getElementsByClassName('pageNav')[0]
```

CSS

```
#contentBody > section { display:none; }
#contentBody > section.active { display: block; }
```

Comment: Wouldn't I have to call the proper array value still for '.active' in your javascript example with my html strucure. I would think because of my structure the active blocks would load into the the DOM the same(ie. the user order selection). Although this does give me a idea.

Comment: Thank you for that idea although I took it a different route the essential concept was the same. instead I now use the following: 'document.getElementById('subNav').innerHTML = document.getElementById( classID ).getElementsByClassName('pageNav')[0].innerHTML;'

Comment: The visible section would be the only one with the class `active` so you would not need to select from an array of elements.

Answer (score 1):

A good way do handle the page state and detect what content should be visible is the html5 history api. It also has the advantage that the url is updated on content changes (something i was missing on "the mind company"). Check out the mozilla page or google some examples. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: Wouldn't that be a issue with the other page elements reverting back to their previous states?

Comment: I see a function that may assist replaceState();  Oh boy more reading!  Quirky web.  Thank you I will be looking further into this

Comment: I dont know about using this method to do what I need but this does help me get closer to my deep linking idea.